# Conditional projection using ternary operator in LINQ Select

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, c#-6.0

Let's say, we have a table `Fruits` and I have written a method GetFruitName. 
Fruits has a column `FruitName` of `string/varchar` type which can be null.
So, if the FruitName is null, I simply want to return FruitName as fruit concatenated with FruitId.

I am getting this error on invoking the method.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

```
public class Fruit
{
    public Guid FruitId { get; set; }
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
}

public string GetFruitName(Guid key)
{
    return dbContext.Fruits
                    .Where(fr=> fr.FruitId== key)
                    .Select
                    (
                       fr=>  
                         fr.FruitName!= null 
                           ? fr.FruitName
                           : $"Fruit_{fr.FruitId}"
                    )
                    .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Edit:
I was curious if we could do this without using an intermediate variable with null check if statements.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
public string GetFruitName(Guid key)
{
    var fruit = dbContext.Fruits
                         .SingleOrDefault(fr=> fr.FruitId== key);

    // Here is your call. I choosed to return an empty string in case of 
    // a fruit not found. You can return also null. 
    var fruitName = string.Empty;
    if(fruit != null)
    {
        // The fruit with the supplied key found. Get it's name.
        fruitName = fruit.FruitName != null 
                       ? fr.FruitName
                       : $"Fruit_{fr.FruitId}";
    }

    return fruitName;                               
}
```

The problem with your query is not the ternary operator, but the `string.Format` method that is used by the interpolated string `$"Fruit_{fr.FruitId}"`. The complirer translates interploated strings to calls of `string.Format`. For further info regarding interploated strings please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

> I was curious if we could do this without using an intermediate
>   variable with null check if statements.

**Update**

```
public string GetFruitName(Guid key)
{
    return dbContext.Fruits
                    .SingleOrDefault(fr=> fr.FruitId== key)
                    ?.FruitName ?? $"Fruit_{key}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Christos. Yes, I fixed  the solution with this method  already. But i was looking forward to any inline correction without intermediate variable.

Comment: @Ankit Please see my update. I think that without a temp variable you can  write in a way like this.

Comment: Yes, works. Alternatively, it also worked on using regular string concatention.

Comment: Unlike the OP's attempt in the question, you load the full `Fruit` entity from the database and leave it lingering in `dbContext`. You can verify this by inspecting the generated SQL, and by checking `dbContext.Fruits.Local` afterwards. Changing behaviour like this should be mentioned, so that the OP can make an informed decision whether it's okay. Personally, I think the OP's own answer is a better answer to the question asked than this.

Comment: @hvd Correct! However I don't think that for one record is an issue at all. I leave it to the judge of Ankit. Not a problem at all :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of issue with the updated approach. But it was really nice of @hvd elaborating this.

Comment: @Ankit of course it's nice that hvd mentioned this. By the way this happens in both cases, I presented above.

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly, string interpolation does not work in LINQ queries. I reverted to regular string contenation and this worked.

```
 public string GetFruitName(Guid key)
    {
        return dbContext.Fruits
                        .Where(fr=> fr.FruitId== key)
                        .Select
                        (
                           fr=>  
                             fr.FruitName!= null 
                               ? fr.FruitName
                               //changed this line
                               : "Fruit_" + fr.FruitId  //or string.Concat("Fruit_", fr.FruitId)
                        )
                        .SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetFruitName(Guid key)
{
                var query = dbContext.Fruits
                    .Where(fr => fr.FruitId == key)).ToList()
                return query.Select
                      (
                        fr =>
                           fr.FruitName != null
                             ? fr.FruitName
                             : $"Fruit_{fr.FruitId}"
                      )
                      .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

try this.